# Laravel Nova many-to-many resource failing

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-nova

I've got two resources, Bricks and Walls.

The `Brick` model is defined as

```
class Brick extends Model
{
    public function walls()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wall')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and the `Wall` model is defined as

```
class Wall extends Model
{
    public function bricks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Brick');
    }
}
```

The idea being that a wall can have many bricks, and a brick can belong to many walls.

In Nova, I've got the `Wall` fields set up as

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('Name'),
        HasMany::make('Bricks')
    ];
}
```

and the `Brick` fields set up as

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Name'),
            BelongsToMany::make('Walls')
        ];
    }
```

When trying to attach a brick to a wall through the brick resource, I get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: main.wall_id (SQL: insert into "brick_wall" ("brick_id", "wall_id", "created_at", "updated_at") values (5, 1, 2018-11-18 22:08:23, 2018-11-18 22:08:23))`, and when trying to add a brick to a wall through the wall resource I get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: bricks.wall_id (SQL: select * from "bricks" where "bricks"."wall_id" = 1 and "bricks"."wall_id" is not null)`

I've tried switching the `belongsToMany` and `hasMany` relationships but it doesn't help.

---

Edit: Here's the scheme for the intermediate table

```
Schema::create('brick_wall', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('brick_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('wall_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('brick_id')->references('id')->on('brick_id');
            $table->foreign('wall_id')->references('id')->on('wall_id');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many to many relationship, you have to had intermediate table, for example `brick_wall` in your mysql database, to establish many to many relationship between `brick` table and `wall` table. It contains column `brick_id` and `wall_id` and having foreign key relations to `brick` table and `wall` table.

To define many to many relationship, both model use `belongsToMany` function from Eloquent. It will find relationship between `brick` and `wall` table with `{tableName}_id` as default column name as primary key and foreign.

If you are using non standard eloquent name as primary key and foreign key, you can refer to eloquent laravel official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Already had an intermediate table in place, pretty sure it follows the Eloquent naming conventions but I've added the schema to the question

Comment: Just realised the mistake, referenced on the field name not the table name, cheers for helping me get there